A new piece on the chessboard
I'm not sure if this chess piece is actually new,
but this problem comes from group theory.
We are considering the following graph.
Each vertex represents a square on a chessboard and each edge is
a legal move of the following fairy chess piece.
A Tor-Regent is a fairy chess piece that moves one square horizontally, vertically,
or along one diagonal
(parallel to the main diagonal, for $8\times8$ is the white diagonal).
Additionally, if the piece is located at the edge or corner of the board, it "wraps" around the edges, as if the chessboard were on a torus.
Fig.1 shows all variants of the Tor-Regent location on a chessboard.


Problem 1. Given an $n\times n$ chessboard, $n\geq3$, what is the
minimum number of Tor-Regent pieces required to control all squares on
the board, such that no two pieces attack each other?


Problem 2. What is the maximum number of Tor-Regent pieces that can be
placed on an $n\times n$ chessboard, $n\geq3$, so that no two pieces
attack each other?

These problems are analogous to classical chess problems involving standard pieces,
such as queens or rooks, where the goal is to either minimize the number of pieces needed to dominate the board or maximize the number of pieces that can coexist without threatening each other.
We solved these problems for $3\leq n\leq7$, which is sufficient for our purposes. However, already for $n=8$ it is an open question.
We will use the terms: an independent set of chess pieces, a dominating set of pieces, and the independent and independent domination numbers.
We will also use the notation:
$\alpha(TR_{m,n})$ is the independent number Tor-Regent pieces on a $m\times n$ chessboard, i.e., the size of the largest independent set of Tor-Regent pieces;
$i(TR_{m,n})$ is independent domination numbers
i.e., the size of the smallest maximal independent set of Tor-Regent pieces.
By the symbol $TR_{m,n}$ we denote a Tor-Regent's graph for a $m\times n$ chessboard.
If $m=n$, then we're going to write $TR_n$ instead of $TR_{n,n}$.
The following equations are valid:
$i(TR_3)=3$, $\alpha(TR_3)=3$;
$i(TR_4)=3$, $\alpha(TR_4)=4$;
$i(TR_5)=4$, $\alpha(TR_5)=7$;
$i(TR_6)=6$, $\alpha(TR_6)=12$;
$i(TR_7)=7$, $\alpha(TR_7)=14$.
We give some pictures (see Fig 2-5) instead of a proof.
To summarise. Here's my question:

What are the values of $i(TR_8)$ and $\alpha(TR_8)$?

PS. Of course, it will be great if someone knows the solution to general problems 1 and 2.
PSS. I know that $\alpha(TR_8)\geq18$ and $i(TR_8)\leq 11$.
Edit 1.
Going along with Calvin Lin's wishes we will prove both formulas for $n=7$ here.
It is easy to see that $i(TR_n)\geq\lceil n^2/7\rceil$ for any $n\geq1$.
This means that $i(TR_7)\geq7$.
As we can see from Fig. 5, the equality $i(TR_7)=7$ actually holds.
With the second formula it's a little more complicated.
Let's assume that
some rank of the board contains at least $3$ pieces.
Figure A below shows the case of three pieces.

(The case where a rank contains 4 pieces is considered similarly.)
We see that these three pieces attack all the squares of neighbouring rank except one.
Thus in two neighbouring ranks we can put no more than $4$ pieces.
It follows that $\alpha(TR_7)\leq14$.
Edit 2.
I clarified the captions under the figures. Fixed typos in PSS.
Added pictures for the chessboard $8\times8$.
So, the question can now be clarified as follows: $i(TR_8)=10$ or $11$?
Further, $\alpha(TR_8)\geq18$ and perhaps even $\alpha(TR_8)=18$.
But how to prove it?
Edit 3.
Thanks to RobPratt's excellent answer, not only do we now know that $i(TR_8)=11$ and $\alpha(TR_8)=19$, but we now have the opportunity to think about two series of numbers, neither of which are in the OEIS.
But still, forgive my stubbornness, I would like to have a purely theoretical justification for at least the $8\times8$ board.
Well, for now there is hope of getting a general formula for each of these two series of numbers.




1/ Please include proofs instead of just pictures to the extent that you can.. Ideally also explain why you've having difficulty extending the solution. $\quad$ 2/ Please include pictures for $8 \times 8$.

You might make progress by computing the first few numbers and putting them in OEIS.

@CalvinLin Thank you for your interest in the challenge and your comment. I will try to add a proof of one of the cases and draw pictures for independent sets on an 8x8 chessboard.

@Mason Thank you. It is interesting. Will do it.

Here are the values for $n\in\{3,\dots,20\}$, obtained via integer linear programming with a binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ to indicate whether a piece appears in square $(i,j)$:
\begin{matrix} n & i(n) & \alpha(n) \\ \hline3 & 3 & 3 \\ 4 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 4 & 7 \\ 6 & 6 & 12 \\
7 & 7 & 14 \\ 8 & 11 & 19 \\ 9 & 13 & 27 \\ 10 & 16 & 30 \\ 11 & 19 & 37 \\ 12 & 23 & 48 \\ 13 & 2
6 & 52 \\ 14 & 28 & 61 \\ 15 & 36 & 75 \\ 16 & 39 & 80 \\ 17 & 46 & 91 \\ 18 & 50 & 108 \\ 19 & 55
 & 114 \\ 20 & 60 & 127 \\ \end{matrix}
Here's a maximum independent set for $n=8$:

Here's a maximum independent set for $n=19$:

Here's a maximum independent set for $n=20$:


Do you have examples for the optimal solution for n=19 and 20? The optimal solution in general will probably have these diagonals, the only thing is to find how to accommodate the torus wrapping,  and it is probably possible to make some conjectures based on larger solutions...

That's a wonderful answer. I'm looking at the two series of numbers you've received and enjoying the opportunity to study them.
